# Create geofence in background

Tags: android, background, background-service, android-geofence

Can I create a geofence with the app in background (for example with a service) or with the app closed? The goal is create a geofence without the app on foreground. I have tried start the activity and move it to background, but I have seen how the app is opened and I don't want this.

Also, I have tried create geofence in background service in "*onStartCommand()*", but when I need create *GeofenceRequester*, I need the Activity value and I cannot get it.

Thank you for advance.

Comment: I am wrestling with the same issue.  Have you found a solution?

Comment: can you find the solution?